# Javascript, weed out questionnaires that contain a "No"

Tags: javascript

I have this questionnaire, 5 Y/N questions yield info based on the answer combination. But I just want to plain weed out all those that question #5 is a "No". Help?

```
function validateform() {
    var q1 = getRBtnName('q1');
    var q2 = getRBtnName('q2');
    var q3 = getRBtnName('q3');
    var q4 = getRBtnName('q4');
    var q5 = getRBtnName('q5');
    var qans = q1+q2+q3+q4+q5;

    if (qans.length < 5) { 
        alert('Missing selection'); 
        return; 
    }

    alert(qans+'.html');  // for testing purposes only
```

Comment: You only want to weed out question #5?

Comment: What does "weed out" mean? Prevent submission? Or have the user believe they've submitted but you ignore it, or...?

Comment: If the questionnaire shows a Yes for question #5, return a rejection notice to the user regardless of the rest of the answers.

Comment: or yes, have the user believe they submitted it and I ignore it, that makes sense.

Comment: So...
 
`if (q5 == '0'){
  alert('something');
  return;
}`

I'm not sure what the values involved are, but that follows what you did for 'missing selection'.

Comment: I placed it as  `  if (qans.length < 5) { 
        alert('Missing selection'); 
        return; 
    }

    alert(qans+'.html');  // for testing purposes only                                                          if (q5 == '0'){ alert('something'); return; }  `   and a couple other places but I don't get it right. It still returns a YYYN.html etc. I have no idea where exactly it should go.

Comment: Based on question 5 the person can be assumed they do not qualify for the benefit for which the questionnaire is about. And since each combination has an equally combined answer, it's just easier let those people right away know they just don't qualify.

Comment: At the risk of making an obvious suggestion, for which there are reasons against - wouldn't it be far better if question 5 was the first one? Why would you make them answer 5 questions before finding out they don't qualify?

Comment: "It still returns a YYYN.html etc." Is it possible that you need to do a check against q5 == 'N', and not q5 == '0'?

Comment: Yes, I had changed '0' for 'N', don't have my computer at hand but want to try this code. The organization gave me the questions in that order, any changes gotta discuss with them.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand...

```
function validateform() {
    var q1 = getRBtnName('q1');
    var q2 = getRBtnName('q2');
    var q3 = getRBtnName('q3');
    var q4 = getRBtnName('q4');
    var q5 = getRBtnName('q5');
    var qans = q1+q2+q3+q4+q5;

    if (q5 == "N") { 
        alert("You don't qualify.  Get outta here."); 
        return false; 
    }

    if (qans.length < 5) { 
        alert('Missing selection'); 
        return false; 
    }

    alert(qans+'.html');  // for testing purposes only

}
```

Comment: Thank you WildcardM!!! Beautiful, I just sent a working copy to the organization's president. Credit will be given. :)